# how to get editable text value from database in android

Tags: android

I am fetching the text from database and append to edit text.it display all text in edittext.now i am changing some text in editext .i want what i am changed text in  editext that values i want print

```
             this my listview code
                JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("mainmenu");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainmenulist);
        adapter = new EditMainMenulistview(this, json);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);(here i can pass json array to EditMainMenulistview.java)
```

Menuoption

```
                 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.text:
        String gou=adapter.edittext.toString();//here only i want print all editext names i can change
        System.out.println(gou);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

EditMainMenulistview.java

```
        public class EditMainMenulistview extends BaseAdapter {
protected static Context Context = null;
int i;
public String editnewmainmenu, menuname,edittext;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname, itemcode;
public String[] itemnames, itemcodes;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public EditMainMenulistview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    // inflater =
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemcodes = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
            itemname = image.getString("menuname");
            itemcode = image.getString("menucode");
            itemnames[i] = itemname;
            itemcodes[i] = itemcode;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(itemnames[i]);
        System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);

    EditText text = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);


    image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

    text.append(itemnames[position]);
     edittext = text.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(edittext);
    //Toast.makeText(Context, edittext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return vi;

}

   }
```

the above cod i can append all database itemnames to edit text.now i can change some item names in edit text .what i am changed itemnames i click menu option it prints all changed values of edit text

Comment: Your question is barely understandable. Please reformulate.

Comment: sir please give suggestion how to get change editext values while clicking option menu please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you actually want .

[This could be of some help:](http://pastebin.com/C6KPmSjc)

> How to get editable changed value from edittext customized list view and stored in array in android
>
> ```
> View vi = convertView;
>
> vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
>
> EditText text = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
> text.append(itemnames[position]);//here i append so many itemnames append to edittext
> ```
>
> This method is called to notify you that, within *s*, the *count* characters 
>   beginning at *start* have just replaced old text that had length *before*.
>
> ```
> mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
>             int count) {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
>         int after) {
>     }
> });
> ```